# How to determine waiting keyboard input event of a another process which is invoked by Java

Tags: java, process

Assume that you have written a C/C++ application (a.exe) to periodically get keyboard input from the user.
for example .
1st keyboard input

```
cin>>id;
```

2nd keyboard input within non deterministic time period

```
cin>>name;
```

What I want to do is invoke the C++ program (a.exe) using whatever process managing mechanism (java.lang.Process..etc)  and determine the keyboard input event from the Java application.

This mechanism is implemented in Netbeans IDE. Can someone suggest a way to achieve this or if someone know the source location where this mechanism in implemented in netbeans IDE or another open source IDE?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'this is implemented in Netbeans'?

Comment: (By the way, this looks like something you could do with pipes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365141%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

Comment: The netbeans console behave exactly similar to my requirement. If we write a program to get keyboard input, the netbeans console is able to handle the situation properly. since netbeans is implemented in Java it should be possible to implement my requirement in Java.

Comment: I may be wrong, but as far as I know the netbeans console is only a system console (`cmd` in Windows) that actually runs your program. There is no communication there of the kind that you require, your program is actually being run from that console.